# Explicación del método sort con criterio de comparación pasado por parámetro en javascript

Tags: javascript, ordenamiento

Tengo una duda al respecto del código que pongo a continuación.
El proposito del ejercicio es completar un array de números aleatorios para posteriormente ordenarlos de forma ascendente posicionando en primer lugar los números pares y luego los impares.

Mi resolución del ejercicio fue mucho más arcaica que esta, primero ordene todos los números para posteriormente usar el criterio del módulo para establecer cuales eran pares e impares.

No obstante, el documento donde he buscado el ejercicio ofrece la siguiente respuesta que no entiendo bien.

```
 var numeros = new Array(5);
       
        for (let i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            numeros[i] = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
        }

 numeros.sort(function (a, b) {
            let resultado = a % 2 - b % 2 || a - b;
            console.log(resultado);
            return resultado;

        });
```

En la parte de la función de comparación es donde me surgen las dudas.

```
function (a, b) { return = a % 2 - b % 2 || a - b;}
```

Hasta donde yo se, una función de comparación espera valores que sean superiores, inferiores o iguales a cero para establecer el orden de los elementos. Sin embargo, veo que aquí utiliza un operador lógico OR ||.  Entiendo que estos operadores solo tienen sentido cuando los operandos de ambos lados son booleanos, entonces, ¿está casteando ambos resultados a un boolean?

Otra duda, si por ejemplo varias de las primeras posiciones del array son todos numeros primos, por tanto sus residuos son 1, al hacer la resta de los residuos sera 0, entonces en ese caso estaría cambiándose las posiciones dentro del array de esos elementos?

Agradecería mucho cualquier explicación.
Un saludo.

Comment: En javascript cualquier valor puede pasarse a "booleano". Lo pongo entre comillas porque en realidad son valores `falsy` y/o `truthy`. Un string `"hola"` sería truthy, un string `""` sería falsy. Lo mismo es aplicable a números, cualquier número diferente a 0 es truthy, con lo que está haciendo esa operación es devolver el valor de `a % 2 - b % 2` excepto si ese módulo es 0, en cuyo caso devuelve la resta de `a - b` directamente. `null` y `undefined` también son falsy, por eso en JS es mejor poner `if (x)` y no `if (x !== null && x != undefined)`. Así que ese `||` está operando con boolean :)